# Is there any ultimate good documentation about Apache Cassandra?

Tags: database, documentation, cassandra

I found a lot. But which one is the best? And why? I didn't find yet anything really complete and centralized in one good article or documentation. At least a good book? Thanks.

Comment: Which documentation is best? How can anyone answer that? That is too subjective. The best documentation is that which answers your individual questions/ issues.

Comment: your answer is subjective, every opinion is subjective. 90% of stackoverflow questions are subjective. That's why the people can vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our (Riptano's) Cassandra documentation is probably the best one-stop resource: http://www.riptano.com/docs

A good complement from the ASF wiki is http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArticlesAndPresentations.

Answer (score 5):

The [Cassandra High Performance Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/cassandra-apache-high-performance-cookbook/book) is the most recent book. It has a how-to format but along the way documents many of the features.

Comment: It's a great book covering and explaining stuffs that are hard to grasp otherwise.